# InvalidOperationException: Role testRole does not exist

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I was trying to let the accountController to assign roles to each newly registered user automatically, so I've ended up doing something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                //there is where the error is being raised.
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "testRole");

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                 //here goes some code
                 //have also adding this line of code inside this if stmt
                //await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "testRole");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

I did what other posts on StackOverFlow recommended but, I keep having this error:
InvalidOperationException: Role TESTROLE does not exist.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore+d__34.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager+d__104.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   WebApplication2.Controllers.AccountController+d__17.MoveNext()
>   in AccountController.cs

Notes:

- I was using PostgreSql on my project, so I've created a new project
  with MSSQL and ended up with the same error.
- I've made sure that the testRole is being in the table AspNetRoles. So ,there's no problem with that either!

Comment: Does TestRole exist in the AspNetRoles table?

Comment: if you decided to go back to PostgreSQL it would work there too

Comment: Thanks a lot It did work on my project. I didn't notice that the normalized one is the deal breaker there! I thank you again !

Comment: its a bad assumption on MS's part for assuming that someone won't fill but they check for it during the query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so testRole is exact name which would then get normalized to TESTROLE how was TestRole created? I say this because Identity looks for the normalized version. Exception is pretty clear that it doesn't exist in this case. Basically if you didn't use RoleManager then something is wrong with the way you created the role

Another way to create the role would be using your database context and add in new roles that way but if you didn't use caps for the NormalizedName field entry then this is the error you will get